# My 1440x900 resolution is not recognized

Tags: resolution, display, xrandr

Today I decided to install Ubuntu 11.10, and it did not recognize my resolution - 1440x900.

This has already happened in other versions of Ubuntu. However, in 11.10 I cannot get this resolved. Can anyone help me?

My PC:

- Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ

  - Proview 19'' 1440x900
- Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric)
- Kernel Linux - 3.0.0-12-generic

I tried the instructions in [this blog post](http://www.45graus.com.br/recuperar-resolucao-perdida-na-atualizacao-pro-ubuntu-10-10,blog-testsoh,70329.html).

Answer (score 2):

Please generate an /home/"username"/xorg.conf.new that you can edit by adding a known good modeline in the applicable monitor section (if there are more than one).

To have the 1280x1024 resolution from the start on my HP vs17e monitor I included:

```
option "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
```

(But I use Radeon driver on X600 discrete pci-e display adp, not the Intel.)

Save it under another name like `/home/username/20-Proview.conf.`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for console 1, log in, and run:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for console 2, log in, and run:

```
sudo cp 20-Proview.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to return to console 1 and run:

```
sudo start lightdm
```

If there is no no error you get the greeter login.

If there is an error, return to console 2 and run:

```
less /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

You can read this and see where the error (if any) occurred.

To undo a mistake just run:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-Proview.conf
```

(I apologise if I introduced typos--sometimes xorg has to be with capital X, as is the case for that log file.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with my monitor. Have you tried the usual randr commands?

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --rate 60
```

Of course, change the value on rate to what refresh rate you want, and VGA-1 should be changed to what the name of your monitor is. If you need to find out the name just do

```
xrandr
```

and it will show you a list.

Comment: Well, I can even change the resolution. But when I restart from a mistake and goes back to what it was before. That is, I can not set the resolution.

It must be because of LightDM. Why the other method, I ran a command that changed the resolution.

Comment: if the commands work to change the resolution just make an sh file with the commands in it, then go on the unity launcher and search for "startup applications" and add a new application and add as the command "sh /path/to/file.sh"

Comment: It can be ... but I would like to change the resolution of LightDM too. What can not be done by "startup applications". Any tips?