# Ubuntu 13.04 Intel Graphics on Intel Desktop Board DH87RL

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

My new desktop PC has, Intel Desktop Board DH87RL and HPw1707 LCD screen that can support apprx. 1440x900 resolution. But I only get 1024x768 and 800x600.

I tried [Intel Linux graphic installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2) but still no luck with a higher resolutions.

Can someone please help me, what I can do get this issue fixed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this-

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1440x900 xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900
 --rate 60
```

> Of course, change the value on rate to what refresh rate you want, and
>   VGA-1 should be changed to what the name of your monitor is. If you
>   need to find out the name just do

```
xrandr
```

> and it will show you a list.

From here,
[My 1440x900 resolution is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65554/my-1440x900-resolution-is-not-recognized)

See this too

> This worked for me on an old Dell Optiplex GX270:
>
> Launch a terminal window and enter the following command:

`sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

> Enter your password if prompted. The xorg.conf document will then
>   launch in gedit.
>
> *Add the following line under Section "Monitor":*
>
> **Modeline     "1440x900_60.00"  106.47  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901**
>    **904 932  -HSync +Vsync**
>
> *Add following lines under Section "Screen":*

```
SubSection "Display"
      Viewport       0 0
      Depth         24
      Modes         "1440x900_60.00" EndSubSection
```

> Select "Save" from the file menu, then "Close".
>
> Shut down any running programs and then restart X Server using
>   Ctl+Alt+Backspace. Log back in and go to System > Preferences > Screen
>   Resolution. Choose Resolution 1440x900 and then Apply. You may need to
>   restart the PC for the change to take effect without display errors.
>
> This may work with other widescreen resolutions. To generate modelines
>   for different resolution/refresh rate combinations use the command gtf
>   [hres] [vres] [refresh rate], e.g. for a monitor with 1680x1050 native
>   resolution:

```
gtf 1680 1050 60
```

From here, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022011

> I have a similar problem with my monitor. Have you tried the usual
>   randr commands?

Comment: Thanks @aaditya-bagga - but here is the problem - as of 13.04 there is no xorg.conf files. So I think your solution may work, if there is a way of overriding display settings. But I can't just figure out, where to put these settings, as they are all changed now.

Comment: yeah you seem to be right, no xorg.conf by default. But see the second link..perhaps you can create the files in your home folder.